# Select object given identifier in Marshmallow

Tags: python, nested, marshmallow

I'm relatively new to the Marshmallow package, and I'm trying to accomplish the following which is better explained through example.

Assume we have the following object:

```
data = {
    artists: [
       {
           id: 42,
           name: "Foo"
       },
       {
           id: 43,
           name: "Hector"
       }
   ],
   albums: [
       {
          name: "The Bar",
          artist: 42
       }

   ]
}
```

And the following schema:

```
class ArtistSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int()
    name = fields.Str()

class AlbumSchema():
    name = fields.Str()
    artist = <see below>
```

Is there any way, that when I use Marshmallow to load my data, I can set the artist in the AlbumSchema to be the artist object corresponding to the given id? Currently I iterate through the artists but I am wondering if there is a smarter way of doing this using Marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
artist = fields.Nested(ArtistSchema)
```

See https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/nesting.html for details.

In general, ORMs usually support foreign keys so you shouldn't need to do much work to set them.

Comment: This doesn't work because I'm not directly nesting the ArtistSchema object